# INSERT JSON One by one

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I get some problem with insert json at LOOP to Oracle DB.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "identificationMethod": "N",
            "idNumber": "7779",
            "bonuses": [
                {
                    "dateFrom": "2023-01-01",
                    "dateTo": "2023-12-31",
                    "value": 500,
                    "currency": "PLN",
                    "name": "11DOD",
                    "kind": "1"
                },
                {
                    "dateFrom": "2023-01-01",
                    "dateTo": "2023-12-31",
                    "value": 500,
                    "currency": "PLN",
                    "name": "22DOD",
                    "kind": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "identificationMethod": "N",
            "idNumber": "7790",
            "bonuses": [
                {
                    "dateFrom": "2023-01-01",
                    "dateTo": "2023-12-31",
                    "value": 500,
                    "currency": "PLN",
                    "name": "333DOD",
                    "kind": "1"
                },
                {
                    "dateFrom": "2023-01-01",
                    "dateTo": "2023-12-31",
                    "value": 500,
                    "currency": "PLN",
                    "name": "444DOD",
                    "kind": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What i need to do is insert first Item with 2 bonuses, next second item with another bonuses

```
  FOR IDOD IN (  SELECT
                    json.*
            FROM
                    json_table(i_body,'$.items.bonuses[*]' COLUMNS( DATE1 PATH '$.dateFrom',
                    DATE2 PATH '$.dateTo',
                    value1 PATH '$.value',
                    value2 PATH '$.currency',
                    name PATH '$.name',
                    kind PATH '$.kind' )) json)
        LOOP
END LOOP;
```

The case is to replace * in '$.items.bonuses[*]' with 0 next whit 1 next 2.... etc. HOW ?!

I try to use variables but nothing work.

Comment: Do not loop in SQL, use set processing. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p8tSxMjK)

Comment: It look like solution. :) Insert item and find idnumber and insert bonuses